# In R: run a function through a list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

Is it possible to run a function through a list of matrices?
The function multkw from the package `ULT` requires a matrix of the same length as the x variable (`data$S_M`). I have a list of matrices (`my_list`) that I want to run through the function. I have provided the data and my list below and also an example for how to run the function with a matrix. Also what I have tried so far and the error.

data

```r
data <- structure(list(ID = c("BLA80", "BLA80", "BLA31", "BLA31", "BLA79", 
                      "BLA79", "BLA42", "BLA42", "BLA283", "BLA283"), S_M = c("BEFORE", 
                                                                              "AFTER", "BEFORE", "AFTER", "BEFORE", "AFTER", "BEFORE", "AFTER", 
                                                                              "BEFORE", "AFTER"), average_Ca = c(1596974.03, 1473014.143, 2586409.745, 
                                                                                                                 3682684.657, 2520483.128, 1821912.382, 2721958.618, 2748744.864, 
                                                                                                                 1328664.242, 1185459.179), average_Ba = c(16.15156258, 20.09711394, 
                                                                                                                                                           28.90255736, 46.20374139, 19.4043364, 28.08272881, 17.27731536, 
                                                                                                                                                           35.38934084, 12.43289018, 23.52246807), average_Cu = c(1.541614794, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.272199498, 0.605696247, 0.835403944, 1.101976967, 0.968764031, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.627720498, 1.388735396, 0.91716115, 0.936442436), average_K = c(1109.095542, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1657.282202, 718.370902, 823.254076, 575.3425151, 1023.087054, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    580.705691, 1230.217192, 1031.424583, 1511.920228), average_Mg = c(4396.94302, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       4870.3585, 4947.200358, 5068.28785, 5203.984999, 5071.13643, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       4479.919729, 5030.887032, 5452.903721, 5553.852132), average_Mn = c(20.83182396, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           36.80478114, 22.8397099, 40.16526756, 18.38159317, 29.69941914, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           20.58043487, 43.34693371, 22.41434749, 43.38435577), average_Pb = c(2.55094084, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               4.660350302, 0.979823896, 4.549917977, 2.601128278, 5.440631199, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1.011520964, 5.865883295, 2.943337175, 6.182218068), average_Sr = c(113.8450974, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   112.6037395, 126.1247052, 112.5135425, 114.8274129, 115.0819017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   120.4794982, 126.0247999, 117.5843842, 128.1751451), average_Zn = c(192.731261, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       199.9528515, 151.0361607, 148.9285955, 174.2455377, 188.3346348, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       170.5113979, 237.6179019, 173.9556326, 218.6832589), zone_width = c(39.94736842, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           18.7, 38.42424242, 31.31034483, 53.15789474, 21.35294118, 40.84210526, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           29.1875, 42.52631579, 15.6)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code to create list of matrices (`my_list`) to run through `multkw` function (y = ...)

```r
x <- c(3,   4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12)

df1 <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(x), function(k) combn(x, k, paste0, collapse = " , ")))
df1<- as.data.frame(df1)

df1
colnames(df1) <- c("col1")

#filter for 3 or more and always include zone_width 
df1 <- df1 %>% filter(str_count(col1, fixed(",")) == 2)
df1

columns_data<- df1

my_list <- apply(
  columns_data,
  1,
  function(i) {
    idx <- strsplit(i, " , ") |>
      unlist() |>
      as.integer()
    
    data[, idx] |>
      as.matrix() |>
      list() 
  }
)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
#if you need to install ULT 
remotes::install_github("jacobmaugoust/ULT")
library(ULT)
#how to run function on matrix of all variables 3:12 (y = matrix) 
multkw(y=data[3:12], data$S_M)
```

I had originally tried to run through the function with lapply. I created a function with the code below but got this error

> Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'

```
funn <- function(y) {
  result <- multkw(y=y, data$S_M)
}

lapply(my_list, funn)
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to run a function through a list of matrices?"* Try something like `lapply(list_of_matrices, function(one_matrix) {...})`

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, but this results in the same error I was already getting...Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'

Comment: My guess (not tested) is the issue is at the end of your `apply()` call: `data[, idx] |> as.matrix() |> list()`. By adding `list()` here, `my_list` ends up as a list of lists, rather than a list of matrices. So try removing `list()`.

Comment: In addition to @zephryl's recommendation: once you remove the trailing `|> list()`, you have the problem that `apply` wants to simplify your data into one large matrix. Fix this by using `apply(..., simplify=FALSE)`, and you get an actual list of matrices instead of a list-of-lists-of-matrices. From there ... another point: referencing `data$S_M` in your `funn` seems very suspect to me. I'm not parsing through whatever your `apply` function is doing (collapsing on `,` and then `strsplit`ing it? Almost certainly unnecessary), but I believe there are misunderstandings of what is happening.

Comment: confusedindividual, once you get past the error and are able to get the code to do _something_, I advise that you verify that its results are exactly what is expected (via somebody else or some other program). This may need to be done with sample data, I don't know, but there are at least two areas of this code that seem to me to be using data (and `data`) in inconsistent ways.

Comment: Thank you for all the help @r2evans! You were right, I was accidentally creating a list of lists. I was able to get it to run by using a loop instead. ```data_table <- tibble(ID = character(), p_value = numeric())
for (item in my_list) {
    a<- (item[[1]])
  ID<- as.data.frame(a[1,])
  print(data$S_M) 
  result<- ULT::multkw(y=item[[1]], data$S_M, print = FALSE)
  p_value<- result$p.value
  print(p_value)
```